# how to add custom validation to product options field?

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation

I'm trying to add custom validation to the product option, I'm following the [tutorial](http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/)
 and here it says to add custom validation element to the attribute `data-validate` like `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-custom-name':true}"`

so far I've tried this:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {

    var rowId = $('#options_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rowOpId ?>_text');

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var data = $(rowId).data("validate"); // default object value

        if (!("validate-custom-name" in data)) {
            $(rowId).extend($(rowId).data("validate"), {"validate-custom-name": true});
        }
    });
});
```

nothing happened so far. it only shows:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[1]" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text product-custom-option" id="options_1_text" aria-required="true">
```

this is the source code of the html element, here you can see that `data-validate` option is not being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 require(['jquery'], function ($) {

     var rowId = $('#options_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rowOpId ?>_text');

     $(document).ready(function(){

         var data = $(rowId).data("validate") ; // default object value

         if (!("validate-custom-name" in data)) {
             var newObj = {"validate-custom-name": true};
             $.extend(data, newObj); //merged both in data variable
             $(rowId).attr("data-validate", JSON.stringify(data)); // set attr() as data() won't work
         }
    });
 });
```

Now output is as desired:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="options[1]" data-validate="{required:true, validate-custom-name:true}" class="input-text product-custom-option" id="options_1_text" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: I can only after 2 days according to the policy.